# speed up wamp server + drupal on windows vista

Tags: optimization, drupal, windows-vista, wamp

My localhost performance with drupal six is pretty slow. I found a solution to add a # before the :: localhost line of the system32/etc/hosts file but this was something I had already done and didn't help much.

does anyone know of any other optimisations that might work?

tHanks

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For quick prototyping of Drupal sites, i recommend the [DAMP stack from Acquia](http://acquia.com/downloads), which includes Drupal, Apache, MySQL and PHP in a quickly deployable package.

As an addition, it alco comes with CCK and Views, so you don't have to download those anymore.

Using the DAMP package can solve some of the speed-problems usually accociated with generic *AMP installations, however, Do Note, that Drupal on windows is known generally to be a bit slower due to the design of windows and the implementation of the *AMP stack on Windows (XAMPP is a large offender.)

If DAMP is still running slow, there are some [tweaks for your windows machine](http://acquia.com/node/456261) that can mak a big difference

Answer (score 1):

You should check this page: http://drupal.org/node/627252

Expecially, but not limiting to: http://drupal.org/node/51263 and http://drupal.org/node/2602

The best ways to improve performance of an application like Drupal is to make it cache web pages, to improve MySQL perfromances and optimise PHP configuration.

There are also some MySQL tuning tools like e.g. http://blog.mysqltuner.com/

HTH

EDIT: this question should be probably better asked on serverfault

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'll check those out. However, I am only in the development stages and I only have a standard install of drupal with a small amount of content. It seems like your answer is more directed to improving the performance of a working website. 

I will definitely check out the links though.